# How long does it take for a question to be answered on this site?

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I noticed from stackexchange.com that this site gets about 11 questions per day. didn't say if they get responses. i submitted a question yesterday and it looked like it was viewed 14 times.

Does this mean that someone just doesn't have an answer or is this site very busy?

Comment: I'll go with "doesn't have an answer due to X reason" or "not interested in the subject matter".

Comment: makes sense @Firelord

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a minority of questions here get an answer. According to https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered, 59% of the non-removed questions received an answer, and many questions are [removed due to roomba](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355097/178179):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not all the questions get an answer. Some questions might not get an answer because nobody knows it. Other questions might not get an answer because they are not interesting or they are not "answerable". If your questions have not get any feedback yet follow the guidance from:

[How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/289691)

---

I just took a look to your profile. You have only one question visible. It has 0 score and three comments. The comments are preventing that your question be automatically deleted by Roomba for being abandoned.

Please bear in mind that comments might be deleted at any time as they are not intented to be permanent.